# SVG filter makes path disappear on Firefox/Safari/iOS

Tags: firefox, svg, safari, svg-filters

Ok, I am trying to apply a filter to an SVG path to make it "glow", I have got it working fine in chrome, but it does not appear to work in Safari/firefox.

I am defining the filters in another SVG as the one the paths are in is generated by an external library (leaflet.js)

Here is simplified test version:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<svg style="position: absolute; top: -20px; width:0;height:0" id="svgFilters" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
 <defs id="svgFilters">
  <filter id='testFilter' filterRes="10 10" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%"
    filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="linearRGB">
   <feComposite in="SourceAlpha" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="8" k3="-0.5" k4="-0.5" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" result="composite"/>
   <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 1
     0 1 0 0 0
     0 0 1 0 0
     0 0 0 1 0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" in="composite" result="colormatrix1"/>
   <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="10 10" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" in="colormatrix1" result="morphology1"/>
   <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10 10" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" in="morphology1" edgeMode="none" result="blur2"/>-->
   <feComposite in="blur2" in2="composite" operator="out" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" result="composite2"/>
   <feMerge x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" result="merge">
    <feMergeNode in="composite2"/>
    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
   </feMerge>
  </filter>
 </defs>
</svg>


<svg width="400" height="200" viewBox="0 -500 500 100" >
 <g>
  <path
   stroke="#ff0000"
   stroke-opacity="1"
   stroke-width="3"
   stroke-linecap="round"
   stroke-linejoin="round"
   stroke-dasharray="8, 6"
   stroke-dashoffset="0"
   filter="url(#testFilter)"
   fill="green"
   fill-opacity="0.2"
   fill-rule="evenodd"
   d="M211 -552L106 -483L245 -512L273 -431L271 -517zM215 -541L192 -523L238 -521L242 -525z">
  </path>
 </g>
 <defs>
  <pattern id="./img/map/greenstripedBG.png51362524558747380820" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="32" height="32">
   <rect width="24" height="24" x="0" fill="#ff0000"></rect>
   <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="./img/map/greenstripedBG.png" width="32" height="32"></image>
  </pattern>
 </defs>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

If I do not apply the filter, the path shows up fine, but the second I try to apply it, the path is not visible in safari/firefox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing all the internal x, y, width and height values seems to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<svg style="position: absolute; top: -20px; width:0;height:0" id="svgFilters" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
 <defs id="svgFilters">
  <filter id='testFilter' x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%"
    filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="linearRGB">
   <feComposite in="SourceAlpha" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="8" k3="-0.5" k4="-0.5" result="composite"/>
   <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 1
     0 1 0 0 0
     0 0 1 0 0
     0 0 0 1 0"  in="composite" result="colormatrix1"/>
   <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="10 10"  in="colormatrix1" result="morphology1"/>
   <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10 10"  in="morphology1" edgeMode="none" result="blur2"/>
   <feComposite in="blur2" in2="composite" operator="out" result="composite2"/>
   <feMerge result="merge">
    <feMergeNode in="composite2"/>
    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
   </feMerge>  </filter>
 </defs>
</svg>


<svg width="400" height="200" viewBox="0 -500 500 100" >
 <g>
  <path
   stroke="#ff0000"
   stroke-opacity="1"
   stroke-width="3"
   stroke-linecap="round"
   stroke-linejoin="round"
   stroke-dasharray="8, 6"
   stroke-dashoffset="0"
   filter="url(#testFilter)"
   fill="green"
   fill-opacity="0.2"
   fill-rule="evenodd"
   d="M211 -552L106 -483L245 -512L273 -431L271 -517zM215 -541L192 -523L238 -521L242 -525z">
  </path>
 </g>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, It is definitely a start. The path is now showing up, It is working fine in firefox now, but in safari I am getting a result of massive blur over the whole path to the point where you can barley see it.

Comment: Seems OK to me when I run my answer in Safari. Did you notice I removed filterRes too. It's obsolete and only Safari supports it these days.

Comment: Yes, That was it. I copied and pasted your answer to my test page and it worked, then re-implemented it in the real version and had the issue. did not notice the filterRes removal, removed it and all is working. I do not know what i am doing with SVG and used an online generator to make the filters.

Comment: The problem is your combination of primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" and then your use of x=100% etc. in your primitive sizings. These 100% will be interpreted as a single userSpace unit (aka the userSpaceOnUse declaration causes 100% to be interpreted as 1.) You cannot mix objectBounding Box (aka %) and userSpaceOnUse (aka pixels) in your primitives within a single filter.